# Invalid address

Tags: swift, alamofire, alamofire-request

My app is crashing a lot lately and it's throwing this as an error:

> NSOperationQueue 0x2806fd260 (QOS: UNSPECIFIED) EXC_BAD_ACCESS
>   KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000000000000.

I can't find the call that causes this problem. Can someone help me solve this problem please?

This is the crash `stacktrace`:

```
0  AlamofireNetworkLogger         0x10203c7b4 (Missing)
1  AlamofireNetworkLogger         0x10203d910 (Missing)
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1829715bc __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 20
3  CoreFoundation                 0x182971588 ___CFXRegistrationPost_block_invoke + 64
4  CoreFoundation                 0x182970a7c _CFXRegistrationPost + 392
5  CoreFoundation                 0x182970728 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 96
6  CoreFoundation                 0x1828ea524 -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1496
7  CoreFoundation                 0x1829701d8 _CFXNotificationPost + 696
8  Foundation                     0x183358814 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 68
9  Alamofire                      0x101fd7a84 closure #1 in SessionDelegate.urlSession(_:task:didCompleteWithError:) (SessionDelegate.swift:451)
10 Alamofire                      0x101fd7460 SessionDelegate.urlSession(_:task:didCompleteWithError:) (SessionDelegate.swift:495)
11 Alamofire                      0x101fd83c0 @objc SessionDelegate.urlSession(_:task:didCompleteWithError:) (<compiler-generated>)
12 myApp                          0x10157e9d4 __InstrumentURLSessionTaskDidCompleteWithError_block_invoke + 4311443924
13 CFNetwork                      0x183183420 __51-[NSURLSession delegate_task:didCompleteWithError:]_block_invoke.182 + 252
14 Foundation                     0x183464f68 __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 16
15 Foundation                     0x183371420 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 72
16 Foundation                     0x183370908 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 740
17 Foundation                     0x183466cec __NSOQSchedule_f + 272
18 libdispatch.dylib              0x182440a38 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
19 libdispatch.dylib              0x1824417d4 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
20 libdispatch.dylib              0x1823e6018 _dispatch_continuation_pop$VARIANT$mp + 412
21 libdispatch.dylib              0x1823e56dc _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 600
22 libdispatch.dylib              0x1823f202c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 372
23 libdispatch.dylib              0x1823f28d0 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 128
24 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1826211b4 _pthread_wqthread + 464
25 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x182623cd4 start_wqthread + 4
```

Comment: It looks like you’re dereferencing `nil` somewhere.

Comment: thank you for ur response. Is there a way to know where i'm doing that? my code is huge and i don't know where to start looking.